# SQL Server - Will a blocked REDO thread cause further blocking on readable secondary replica?

Tags: sql-server, availability-groups

I understand that a redo thread replaying a DDL operation can be blocked by a long-running `SELECT` query on readable secondary replica because the latter holds a `Sch-S` lock thus preventing the former from acquiring a `Sch-M` lock. The question is this - will that blocked DDL operation, in turn, block subsequent `SELECT` queries on that replica by preventing them from acquiring their `Sch-S` locks? If so, it can effectively cause an outage from the user's perspective...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Subsequent reads will be blocked in the scenario you described.

Here is my test.

Microsoft SQL Server 2017 (RTM-CU31-GDR) (KB5021126) - 14.0.3460.9 (X64)
Jan 25 2023 08:42:43
Copyright (C) 2017 Microsoft Corporation
Enterprise Edition (64-bit) on Windows Server 2016 Standard 10.0  (Build 14393: ) (Hypervisor)

A long-running select is running from session 55.

```
BEGIN TRAN
WHILE(1=1)
BEGIN
SELECT *
  FROM [ITDB].[dbo].[TEST]
END
```

While the above select statement is running on Secondary replica I issued this schema change on Primary replica.

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.test
ADD column_b VARCHAR(20) NULL, column_c INT NULL;
GO
```

The redo thread is blocked by session 55 because it could not acquire `LCK_M_SCH_M`.

[image]

I am now running another select statement on the same table from session 134.

```
SELECT *
  FROM [ITDB].[dbo].[TEST]
```

Session 134 is blocked by 149 due to not acquiring `LCK_M_SCH_S`.
[image]

```
<Database name="ITDB">
  <Locks>
    <Lock request_mode="S" request_status="GRANT" request_count="1" />
  </Locks>
  <Objects>
    <Object name="TEST" schema_name="dbo">
      <Locks>
        <Lock resource_type="OBJECT" request_mode="Sch-S" request_status="WAIT" request_count="1" />
      </Locks>
    </Object>
  </Objects>
</Database>
```